# Boolean Logic Or gates and Xor8Way

Tags: boolean-logic

Can somebody clarifier both of them.

What is the difference between Or8Way and Or16?

Would it make sense to create a Xor8Way gate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [OR gate](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_3.html) is a component in digital logic, where the output goes high, if at least one of the inputs is set to high.

An [XOR gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) outputs a high, if an odd number of inputs is set to high.

The gate types mentioned in the question do not adhere to commonly used standards. I would expect the following meaning:

```
Or8Way   an OR gate with 8 inputs
Or16     an OR gate with 16 inputs
Xor8Way  an XOR gate with 8 inputs
```

Due to technological constraints, typical gates do not have more than four inputs. To create an `OR` gate with 8 or 16 inputs one could cascade smaller `OR` gates. An [XOR8](http://www1.pldworld.com/@xilinx/html/technote/tool/manual/15i_doc/alliance/lib/figures/x7885.gif) [can be built](http://www1.pldworld.com/@xilinx/html/technote/tool/manual/15i_doc/alliance/lib/figures/x7885.gif) from two `XOR4` and one `XOR2`.